# Is it sufficient validate iOS 7 receipt in my own server?

Tags: ios, validation, ios7, in-app-purchase, receipt

I'm implementing security in my iOS 7 application for iOS In-App purchases. When testing with LocalIAPStore hack I see that when I call the method [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] the returned receipt is null, so it's all right here.

The problem comes when the user purchases an option without having activated LocalIAPStore. If this is done, a receipt is generated. Then, I send it to my server to check that everything is correct and show purchase, but if active again LocalIAPStore, I keep returning a correct receipt, but has actually purchased another option and this is returned as a calidate.

To verify receipt, what else can I do? What should I check locally to avoid it? Any tips? How do you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I recall from the last WWDC there is no need to use a sever in iOS 7 am I wrong here? Can you clarify what is the scenario you are describing ?

Comment: Example: I purchase IAP, receipt is created. When I activate LocalIAPStore and I will try to purchase IAP, the receipt still valid.

Comment: Still, I've tried LocalIAPStore with third party applications and I can skip protection